# Facing an issue using multiple views using backbonjs

Tags: backbone.js

I have created my separate files for backbonjs views and each file have code like this

```
var appendMessageBox = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            this.render();
        },
        render: function(){
            var html='myhtml'
            var template = _.template( html, {} );
            this.$el.append( template );
        }

    });
```

and i am calling it from my plugin file like this

```
var appendMessageBox_View = new appendMessageBox({ el: jqObj });
```

its working

but when i create multiple files of views and calling them they are not working

Comment: can you post the code from another file

Comment: is the file containing code that call these views get loaded after the views? Also what's the exact error you're getting?

Comment: above code in views/amb.js file and i am calling it from my plugin file plugin.js var appendMessageBox_View = new appendMessageBox({ el: jqObj }); when i create another view file views/ab.js and past another code and call it , i am not getting any error but code does'nt work, have you guys any idea, can we use multiple views in backbon.js?

Answer (score 0):

What do you use to manage all the files? One example is [RequireJS](http://requirejs.org/).

Perhaps you can try to run all the source code in one place first before refactoring to different js files?

Comment: we are following directory pattern, in which all views are in views folder like views/file.name and we have a single file of plugin, form where we are calling these views on need basis, problem is when i call single view its working, but when i create another views and calling them its not working.

Comment: Please post more complete source code so that others can help you out better.

Comment: in console i am getting an error: Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Comment: thanks friends, i have got the solution, there were an issue of recursive calling of function, that's why java script gives me Uncaught RangeError.